# How does a billing client know which Play Store account to query in Android?

Tags: c#, android, google-play, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I'm trying to get a list of active subscriptions from a Play Store account within my app. I was wondering if there's something about the billing client that I'm unaware of that is causing my active subscription queries to only query from one account and not another Play Store account that is active.

```java
    QueryPurchasesParams queryPurchasesParams = QueryPurchasesParams
                    .NewBuilder()
                     .SetProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.Subs)
                    .Build();
                    
                    billingClient.QueryPurchases(queryPurchasesParams, purchaseResponseListener);
```

This is the snippet that queries the purchases and I'm saving them into a list. Once the activity closes, I clear the list. I then attempt to switch accounts on the Play Store app, and then run the subscription activity to display a list for the account that is active but then it displays the previous one. Is this a misunderstanding of BillingClient, or is it something else I don't understand?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a long-standing [issue](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/2), I'm guessing here but if you clear tha app data and cache data for the play store and play services your app would pull the other user info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-app purchases with multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811490/in-app-purchases-with-multiple-accounts)

Comment: @TylerV yeah it does, pretty unfortunate that they haven't done anything about this

Comment: Yeah, i ended up adding a firebase cloud function i can call with the saved purchase token to verify it if the billing client suddenly stops returning a formerly active purchase